# How to use try and except

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

```
hours_work = float(input("How many hours do you work? "))
pay_rate = float(input("How much do you earn per hour? "))
print("You get paid:", hours_work * pay_rate)

try:
  (ten)
except Exception:
  Print(" ten ")

print("That's not a number")
```

I'm confused as to how try and except works while trying to calculate the rate of pay.

Comment: What exactly do you want your code to do?

Comment: @PhanNhatHuy. It's a homework assignment

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you need to be honest when you're trying to get your homework done.

Comment: This is like asking how to use a blender to unlock your front door. If you're patient enough and have a steady hand, you may be able to pull it off, but you could also use a key. `try ... except` is for *exceptional* situations, not for calculating results

Comment: whatcha tryna check with the ```try-except```? personally, i would use it to make sure that the user input received with `input` can be cast to float. normally if it cannot be cast, Py would throw an exception and halt the execution. so to prevent that, i would **try** to cast to float, then **catch** an exception with the **except** line, handle it in the except block (ask user to enter a proper number), then rinse and repeat until i get *sanitized* values from the input.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo. There's an exceptional situation here

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/

Answer (score 1):

`try-except` is used when something can go wrong. In your case, the user can enter an invalid number for one of the inputs, like `'a'` or some other non-numerical characters. You can't do the computation in that case, which is exactly what exceptions are for.

```
try:
    hours_work = float(input("How many hours do you work? "))
    pay_rate = float(input("How much do you earn per hour? "))
    print("You get paid:", hours_work * pay_rate)
except ValueError:
    print('You have to enter a number for this to work.')
```

The `print` statement has to occur in the `try` block if you don't want to use `else`. If you put it after the `except`, it will get executed even if there's an error, and cause another error in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial simplified example to point you in the right direction and introduce the related `try`, `except`, and `else` exception handling constructs.

Example:

```
while True:
    
    hours_worked_str = input("How many hours did you work? ")
    
    # Perform operation that may trigger an exception in try block
    try:
        hours_worked = float(hours_worked_str)

    # If the anticipated exception occurred, handle it
    except ValueError as exc:
        print(exc)
        print("Please try again.")

    # If no exception occurred move on
    else:
        break

print(f"You worked {hours_worked} hours.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
try:
    'I\'m trying to run my body code'
    pass
except:
    'I am activated when the "try" error occurs'
    pass
```

"Except" states:

```
except:
Runs at the time of each error

except ErrorName:
When you only want to run at a specific time error

except ErrorName as value:
When you want to get the cause of the error in the form of a string
```

Answer (score 0):

An error pauses your program execution. Want to continue anyway? Use `try` and `except`.

This can be useful for many situations, one I can think of is a calculator. If your user does division by zero or anything that would land them in math jail, then you'd probably want to display a message to them telling you cannot do that. Put your calculation code inside `try`, and the code to be called when an exception occurs in catch`.